# Can two pointers use the same address? (Code explanation)

Tags: c, pointers

```
int i1;
int i2;

int *ptr1;
int *ptr2;

i1 = 1;
i2 = 2;

ptr1 = &i1;
ptr2 = ptr1;

*ptr1 = 3;
i2 = *ptr2;
```

Can someone explain this code for me please? Specially line number eight, I think that it's assigning the address of pointer1 in pointer2, does that makes pointer2 point to the value 1?

Please someone help me. Thank you.

Comment: `ptr2 = ptr1` assigns the value of `ptr1` (which is the address of `i1`) to `ptr2`.

Comment: There are many pointer tutorials online that explain how pointers work and what is going on behind the scenes. http://karwin.blogspot.se/2012/11/c-pointers-explained-really.html

Answer (score 1):

`ptr2 = ptr1` assigns the value of `ptr1` (which is the address of `i1`) to `ptr2`.  This makes `ptr2` point to the same thing that `ptr1` points to, namely, the variable `i1`.  The value in the location pointed to by `ptr2` is indeed, `1`, but it certainly seems odd to say that `ptr2` points to the value `1`.  The value of `ptr2` is a memory location, and that location currently contain a collection of bits which (when interpreted as an int) represent the value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, multiple pointers can point to the same location, a situation known as [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing). And while the line you mention does make `ptr2` point to the value 1, more importantly it points to the storage of `i1`, as does `ptr1`. So at that point you have three different names to access `i1` by: `*ptr1`, `*ptr2` and `i1` itself. As such the last two lines do have a sequential dependency, and the program ends up with 3 in both `i1` and `i2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i1; //initialize 2 integers
int i2;

int *ptr1; //initialize 2 pointer to integers
int *ptr2;

i1 = 1; //storing values into the integer variables
i2 = 2;

ptr1 = &i1; //pointer ptr1 pointing to the address of the integer variable i1
ptr2 = ptr1; //pointer ptr2 pointing to the address pointed by ptr1 (perfectly ok)

*ptr1 = 3; //value at the address pointed by ptr1 changed to 3 (which changes the value at the address pointed by ptr2 also
i2 = *ptr2; //value at the address pointed by the ptr2 stored in integer variable i2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is writing the value of `ptr1` in the address of `ptr2`. To visualise: the you have an arrow in `ptr1` that says "if you need value1, you can get it right *there*". After the copy, `ptr2` now also has an arrow that says "if you need value1, you can get it right *there*". So you were indeed correct in assuming that `ptr2` points to the value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding pointer in C is the way.

Pointer basically is a variable whose value(R-value) is the address(L-value) of another variable.

Variable has a L-value (memory address where it is stored) and R-value (data value).

So

```
ptr2 = ptr1;
```

mean that you are assigning to the R-value of ptr2 the R-value of ptr1.
Ptr1's R-value contains i1's L-value, so:

```
cout << ptr2;  /* print i1's L-value (a memory address) */
cout << *ptr2; /* print 1, that is i1's R-value */
```